# Python Machine Learning Experts

Tags: machine-learning, python

I'd like to apply some of the more complex supervised machine learning techniques in python - deep learning, generalized addative models, proper implementation of regularization, other cool stuff I dont even know about, etc.

Any recommendations how I could find expert ML folks that would like to collaborate on projects?

Comment: If the question is about finding collaborators... I think this is a bit off topic for this SE site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for finding people and not a data science question

Comment: I would like to learn about data science.  Instead of asking 100 questions on here, why not find someone that would like to work as a team to share his/her insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try some competitions from [kaggle](http://kaggle.com).

Data Science courses from Coursera, edX, etc also provide forums for discussion.

Linkedin or freelance sites could be other possibilities.